# "lightning__RecordPage is not a flow related target" while saving a LWC that is used in a flow?

Tags: lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, metadata, screen-flow

I'm trying to embed a LWC into a screen flow, but when I save the following meta-xml file, I get the "lightning__RecordPage is not a flow related target" error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="wizardAtendimento">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="iconName" type="String" label="Icon name"/>
            <property name="title" type="String" label="Title"/>
        </targetConfig>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="iconName" type="String" label="Icon name" role="inputOnly"/>
            <property name="title" type="String" label="Title" role="inputOnly"/>
            <property name="selectedProduct" type="String" label="Produto selecionado" role="outputOnly"/>
            <property name="selectedType" type="String" label="Tipo de produto selecionado" role="outputOnly"/>
            <property name="selectedReason" type="String" label="Motivo de abertura selecionado" role="outputOnly"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Is there something wrong with this setup? What is the correct way of exposing the properties on the flow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `masterLabel` and `description` attributes, and reducing the target list to a single target (the flow), and removing unnecessary attributes form the properties seem to have solved the issue for me. The only attributes that remained on the properties were `name`, `type` and `role`.

Comment: Do you have more details of what your file looked like at bare minimum to be excepted? Does this work if it is referenced in a flow node somewhere? Simply trying to removed from `lightning__RecordPage`

Answer (score 2):

It somehow does not work when we have multiple targets of different type (especially with Flow target) with multiple targetConfig. I even tested by adding masterLabel, decription as well as with the latest Api version (49.0), but still no luck.

I wanted a component in Managed Package which supports Lightning Page Builder, Flow Screens & Lightning Communities with support for multiple form-factors, since Flow does not support SupportedFormFactors tag, I created separate targetConfig for Flow. But I'm receiving same error as above.

Issue can be resolved by:

1. Removing multiple targets (lightning__FlowScreen).
2. Combining all properties to single targetConfig (comma-separated), but then won't be able to use SupportedFormFactors tag.
3. Create a component wrapper for Flow target.

Answer (score 1):

It seems changing targetConfig is in some cases not allowed once you deploy and place the component to the dev org.
I had to remove all components placed in the dev org with lightning builder, and delete the component source code from project and org using sfdx via VSCode.
I copied the source code before delete, so bring it back to the project, then deploy again. Yes, it somehow worked.